# How to escape output in templates in 2.2 - XSS security

Tags: template, security, phtml, magento2.2

I've noticed that the way we escape data in templates is changing as part of 2.2

> **Escape functions for templates**
>
> For the following output cases, use the specified function to generate XSS-safe output.
>
> **The upcoming release of Magento 2.2 will deprecate these functions.**
>
> Please check back on this page after the 2.2 release for updated documentation on new escape functions.

But I can't find any info on how this will work in 2.2.

My question is, **how will escaping output in templates work in 2.2?** Or how does it currently work in 2.2 if you're reading this after 2.2 has been released.

[Link to XSS on the dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html)

Comment: My answer in the linked duplicate covers escaping methods in Magento 2.2

Comment: Wasn't aware that was for 2.2, I'll mark this as solved by your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This docs could be changed, check latest version [Template Security - Magento 2.2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html)

> Stay tuned — We'll roll out more 2.2 documentation updates in the coming weeks.

---

**Security measures against XSS attacks**

To prevent XSS issues Magento recommends the following rules for escaping output in templates:

- If a method indicates that the content is escaped, do not escape:
  getTitleHtml(), getHtmlTitle() (the title is ready for the HTML
  output)
- Type casting and php function count() don’t need escaping (for
  example echo (int)$var, echo (bool)$var, echo count($var))
- Output in single quotes doesn’t need escaping (for example echo 'some
  text')
- Output in double quotes without variables doesn’t need escaping (for
  example echo "some text")
- For all other cases, escape the data using specific escape functions.

The following code sample illustrates the XSS-safe output in templates:

```
 <?php echo $block->getTitleHtml() ?>
 <?php echo $block->getHtmlTitle() ?>
 <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getTitle()) ?>
 <h1><?php echo (int)$block->getId() ?></h1>
 <?php echo count($var); ?>
 <?php echo 'some text' ?>
 <?php echo "some text" ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $block->getAnchorTextHtml() ?></a>
```

**Escape functions for templates**

For the following output cases, use the specified function to generate XSS-safe output.

**Case:** JSON output

**Function:** No function needed for JSON output.

```
 <!-- In this example $postData is a JSON string -->
 <button class="action" data-post='<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $postData ?>' />
```

**Case:** String output that should not contain HTML

**Function:** escapeHtml

You can pass in an optional array of allowed tags that will not be escaped.

If a tag is allowed, the following attributes will not be escaped: `id`, `class`, `href`, `target`, `style` and `title`. Any other attribute for that allowed tag will be escaped.

`embed`, `iframe`, `video`, `source`, `object`, `audion`, `script` and `img` tags will not be allowed regardless of the content of this array.

If your text contains special characters, they must be encoded as HTML entities, such as `&lt;` for < or `&gt;` for >.

```
<span class="label"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?></span>

// Escaping translation
<div id='my-element'><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginUrl(), $block->getCreateAccountUrl()), ['a']) ?></div>
```

**Case:** URL output

**Function:** escapeUrl

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getCategoryUrl()) ?>">Some Link</a>
<script>
  var categoryUrl = '<?php echo $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getCategoryUrl())) ?>';
</script>
```

**Case:** Strings inside JavaScript

**Function:** In a JavaScript context, use the `escapeJs` function.

In cases where the JavaScript code outputs content onto the page, use the escapeUrl or the escapeHtml function where appropriate.

For example, when a URL output string is inside a JavaScript context, use both `escapeJs` and `escapeUrl`. If you insert the output string from inside a JavaScript context into the DOM, use both `escapeJs` and `escapeHtml`.

**Case:** Strings inside HTML attributes

**Function:** escapeHtmlAttr

```
<span class="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getSpanClass()) ?>">Product Description</span>
<input name="field" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldValue()) ?>" />

<!--  Escaping translation inside attributes -->
<img src="product-blue.jpg" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('A picture of the product in blue')) ?>" />
```

**Static Test**

To check your template for XSS vulnerabilities, you can use the static test XssPhtmlTemplateTest.php in `dev\tests\static\testsuite\Magento\Test\Php\`.

This static test finds all echo calls in PHTML-templates and determines if the output is properly escaped.

It covers the following cases:

- `/* @noEscape */` before output. Output doesn’t require escaping. Test
  is green.
- Methods which contain `"html"` in their names (for example `echo
  $object->{suffix}Html{postfix}()`). Data is ready for the HTML output.
  Test is green.
- AbstractBlock methods `escapeHtml`, `escapeHtmlAttr`, `escapeUrl`, `escapeJs`
  are allowed. Test is green.
- Type casting and php function count() are allowed (for example `echo
  (int)$var`, `(bool)$var`, `count($var)`). Test is green.
- Output in single quotes (for example `echo 'some text'`). Test is
  green.
- Output in double quotes without variables (for example `echo "some
  text"`). Test is green.
- Other of previously mentioned. Output is not escaped. Test is red.

Comment: Yeah but the functions are still being used there, if they are deprecated then surely they shouldn't be using them in the example. So I presume the 2.2 docs haven't been updated fully yet.

Comment: You are right @BenCrook, they are still upgrading docs. But I think they don't remove it after publish on 2.2 docs.
`Stay tuned — We'll roll out more 2.2 documentation updates in the coming weeks.`

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what is announced with 2.2 and mark your answer as correct if it is right when 2.2 is released.